# Connect the interior of two cells with arrows in excel

Tags: excel, vba

With the following codes, I connect two edges of two cells in an excel sheet. How can I do this work for interior of cells (for example center of cells). I change the "left" or "right" with "center" in this code but it does not work.

```
   Sub arrow1()
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight,Range("B2").Left, Range("B2").Top,Range("C10").Left, Range("C10").Top).Select 
        
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen 

   End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A Range doesn't have a Center property, but center can be calculated from Top, Left, Height, and Width

Comment: @chrisneilsen How can I calculate from height or width?

Comment: left + (width/2)

Comment: Yes. This is the most simple answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom SUB with 2 parameters: origin and destiny, to create the arrow:

```
Sub test()
CREATE_ARROW Range("B2"), Range("C10")
End Sub



Sub CREATE_ARROW(ByVal rngSource As Range, ByVal rngDestiny As Range)
Dim MyArrow As Shape
Set MyArrow = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, rngSource.Left + rngSource.Width / 2, _
    rngSource.Top + rngSource.Height / 2, _
    rngDestiny.Left + rngDestiny.Width / 2, _
    rngDestiny.Top + rngDestiny.Height / 2)

MyArrow.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen

Set MyArrow = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. and I can change 2 with another number too. for example 3/4.

Comment: Yes, actually you can make that 2 as another custom parameter when calling the sub so everytime you use it you specify origin, destiny and what ratio (2, 3/4 or whatever you need).